# How to get props type for a passed generic react component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a generic function that takes a react component and returns it wrapped in another component, something similar to recompose pattern.

```
const inject = <T extends (React.Component | React.FC)>(Component: T, props: any) => (children: React.ReactChildren): JSX.Element => <Component {...props}>{children}</Component>
```

And then I would use it like

```
const withContext = inject(Consumer, { value: 1 })
```

Does anyone know how to validate props in the second argument to match `T` ?
What should I use instead of any ?